# Emailing a SharePoint Audience with Custom Actions

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am currently trying to build into sharepoint a workflow that runs against list Items. The workflow checks the conditions and then will need to email a certain global audience from SharePoint central administration. I have seen some code on other sites that allow Custom Actions to be placed into designer but I have not seen something that allows you to send an email to an Audience. Is this possible? Can anyone help me out with this? It would be greatly appreciated.

So basically

IF > Condition Met > Email SharePoint audience members.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easy approach is to create an email enabled security group in AD and add the people you need to that group.  Then configure the audience to use that group as it's membership provider.  Then in your workflow, you can just email that Security Group's email address.

Comment: This approach does not work, sharepoint cannot email an AD security group, It seems that sharepoint cannot find the email addresses for the AD security group members. This was the original approach but found a Dead-End quickly.

Comment: Sorry let me say it like this, As of right now we cannot email an AD security group from a sharepoint workflow. Is this something that is controlled in AD to allow a group to be emailed. I do not want it to email just 1 address but every user in the group individualy.

Comment: If the AD group has an email address associated with it, it will email mygroup@company.com and thus send it to everyone in the group.  We've got several workflows set up that way, emailing to an email enabled security group.

Comment: In case anyone else is suffering from this issue, there is a post over at http://www.spdev.info/2012/11/using-security-groups-with-workflows.html that discusses how to resolve.